# Python - looping through a FOR statement using 'continue' (Craigslist posting)

Tags: python, for-loop, xpath, iteration, continue

I am trying to look for a specific text phrase ('w/d in unit') within a table of attributes in an individual Craiglist apartment posting.  The position of this phrase may vary depending on how many other attributes are listed in that table.  For example, 'w/d in unit' may be located:

1. In position 3:

   - cats are ok;
   - dogs are ok;
   - w/d in unit
2. In position 2:

   - cats are ok;
   - w/d in unit;
   - apartment

To account for the variability in position, my Python code is written:

```
 attr = response.xpath("//*[@class='attrgroup']/span")

    for i in range (0, len(attr)):
        if 'w/d in unit' in attr[i].xpath("text()").extract():
            item["washerDryer"] = attr[i].xpath("text()").extract()
        else:
            continue

    return item
```

My question is:

1. How do I get my `item["WasherDryer"]` to store the value "None" when the statement `if 'w/d in unit' in attr[i].xpath("text()").extract():` is false?
   I could put it under the `else` statement `(where item["WasherDryer"] = "None")`, but then the loop would not continue to iterate into the next `i`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use extract_first and pass a default value to it.
Here is how it can be used:

```
for i in range (0, len(attr)):
     item["washerDryer"] = attr[i].xpath("text()").extract_first(default='None')
```

Comment: Thank you! However, that change did not work.  I revised my original code yesterday and it now works (see answer to question below).

Comment: Nice to hear that! Please post a bit of source file next time. That would greatly simplify the task. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I revised my original code yesterday.  I realized I first needed to determine if the text 'w/d in unit' exists before pursuing iteration.

What we are doing here is:

1) See if the text 'w/d in unit' appears anywhere in the string 'attr'
2) If yes, then proceed to iterate
3) If no, then automatically tag the item['washerDryer'] = 'None'

```
        if 'w/d in unit' in str(attr):
            for i in range (0, len(attr)):
                if 'w/d in unit' in attr[i].xpath("text()").extract():
                    item["washerDryer"] = attr[i].xpath("text()").extract()
                else:
                    continue
        else:
            item["washerDryer"] = "None"
```